# Can't run DrRacket or gracket 7.0

Tags: racket

When I `open DrRacket.app` v7.0 on OSX 10.7.5, I get this error message:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Racket v7.0/DrRacket.app.
```

Running `drracket` from the command line yields some more detail:

```
ffi-lib: couldn't open "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics.dylib" (dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics.dylib, 6): image not found)
  context...:
   "/Applications/Racket v7.0/share/pkgs/gui-lib/mred/private/wx/cocoa/utils.rkt": [running body]
   for-loop
   run-module-instance!125
   for-loop
   [repeats 1 more time]
   run-module-instance!125
   for-loop
   [repeats 1 more time]
   run-module-instance!125
   for-loop
   [repeats 1 more time]
   run-module-instance!125
   do-dynamic-require5
   "/Applications/Racket v7.0/share/pkgs/gui-lib/mred/private/wx/platform.rkt": [running body]
   for-loop
   run-module-instance!125
   ...
```

Any suggestions for what I should try?

I figure that the problem is most likely that I'm running an old version of OSX. CoreGraphics was introduced in 10.8. I've looked for documentation on what OS versions each version of Racket requires, and haven't yet found anything. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: Oh wow. I don't think any of the main developers of Racket have a machine running a version of OS X that old. This is almost certainly a bug with Racket, which should probably be reported, either on github, or the racket mailing list.

Comment: @LeifAndersen Thanks. Will do. (I'm running on an old laptop. It works fine but Apple no longer supports it.)

Comment: For reference, this does look like a bug in Racket that affects older versions of os x. The conversation has moved to: https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/2215 I'm going to see if I can find a way to close it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matthew Flatt kindly answered my question on the [Racket github](https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/2215). *DrRacket* and *gracket* in Racket 7.0 will indeed run on OSXes earlier than 10.8. To get them to work:

1. Change line 41 of `share/pkgs/gui-lib/mred/private/wx/cocoa/utils.rkt` to:

   `(define cg-lib (ffi-lib (format "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics") #:fail (lambda () #f)))`
2. In `share/pkgs/gui-lib/mred/private/wx/cocoa/queue.rkt`, change this line:

   `(define-cg CGEventTapCreate (_fun _uint32 _uint32 _uint32 _uint64
                                     (_fun #:atomic? #t
                                           #:keep mb-detect-box
                                           _pointer _uint32 _id _pointer -> _id)
                                     _pointer
                                     -> _pointer))`

   to:

   `(define-cg CGEventTapCreate (_fun _uint32 _uint32 _uint32 _uint64
                                     (_fun #:atomic? #t
                                           #:keep mb-detect-box
                                           _pointer _uint32 _id _pointer -> _id)
                                     _pointer
                                     -> _pointer) #:fail (lambda () #f))`

   and this line:

   `(define-cg CGEventGetLocation (_fun _pointer -> _NSPoint))`

   to:

   `(define-cg CGEventGetLocation (_fun _pointer -> _NSPoint) #:fail (lambda () #f))`

These changes remove the dependency on CoreGraphics.